# Django saving data from html field to database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am new to Django, I am trying to take input from user using html generated text field and not use django forms.

```
<form action="" method="post">
{ % csrf_token % }
<label for="name">Enter name: </label>
<input id="namefield" type="text" name="name_field" value="Default name">
<input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

I want to save the name to my database, without creating a django form and taking in data from the form and saving it in the database via views.py file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view:

```
If request.method == 'POST' :
          name = request.POST['field_name']
          #now you can save them into related model
          MyModel.objects.create(username=name,other fields goes here)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create in the `views.py` file a method in which the templates and the logic of it, an example can be the following

```
@csrf_exempt
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        var1 = request.POST.get('var1')
        var2 = request.POST.get('var2')
        var3 = request.POST.get('var3')

        #Save to the database here

        return render_to_response(
            'home.html',
            {'message': 'Update Success', }
        )
    else:
        return render_to_response(
            'home.html',
            {}
        )
```